How to solve ls cannot access?
When I use ls -al $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/ it's no problem, but when I use ls -al $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ it will apear the text ls cannot access. I search in many website, but I cannot solve this problem.
MyOS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Sorry if I write false grammar.


... that looks like a simple typographical error (extentions versus extensions)

@steeldriver That is an answer.

This is most likely a typo on your part.
You've used extentions instead of extensions.  This is why you get the error message you see, because it's an incorrect spelling.
